# How to setup a MySQL Database Connection with OSGI?

Tags: mysql, connection, osgi

I try to get a Connection to my MySQL Database but the normal way with Class.forname() doesn't work because of the Class Loader Hirachie of OSGI . An i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Go read this: http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access

Answer (score 0):

Look at Pax JDBC: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/MySQL+Driver+Adapter

This will register a DataSourceFactory for the MySQL database which you can then use to create DataSource. See http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/jdbc/DataSourceFactory.html

I think the Pax JDBC MySql driver has some constraints, it does not full implement the specification, so please read the instructions carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi a bundle's classloader can only see packages which are explicitly imported by that bundle in it's manifest. So a Class.forname will not work for packages that are not imported.

The straightforward solution would be to add a Import-Package header in the manifest for the com.mysql.jdbc package. If you than try to load (for example) com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, it will work.

Adding explicit Import-Packages for JDBC drivers would make it impossible to switch drivers without changing the import-package headers. For this you could consider using a DynamicImport-Package: *. This will allow the bundle to find classes after the bundle wiring. Note that in most situations, this should never be used, because now you're back to the possibility of runtime classloading exceptions that OSGi normally prevents for you. In the case of JDBC, it can be the right solution however.